# Accessing Entry validator

Tags: c#, validation, xaml, xamarin.forms

Here is the first version of code:

```
MultiValidationBehavior myValidator = new MultiValidationBehavior {
            InvalidStyle = invalidEntryStyle,
            Flags = ValidationFlags.ValidateOnValueChanging,
            Children = {
                new TextValidationBehavior { MinimumLength = 5 },
                new CharactersValidationBehavior { CharacterType = CharacterType.Digit, MaximumCharacterCount = 0 }
             }
           }
        };

        Entry myEntry = new Entry
        {
            Text = "string",
            Behaviors =
            {
                myValidator
            }
            
        };
```

In this example if I wish to check the validator's state I can call `myValidator.IsValid`

Now the second version of the same code:

```
Entry myEntry = new Entry
        {
            Text = "string",
            Behaviors =
            {
                new MultiValidationBehavior {
                  InvalidStyle = invalidEntryStyle,
                  Flags = ValidationFlags.ValidateOnValueChanging,
                  Children = {
                      new TextValidationBehavior { MinimumLength = 5 },
                      new CharactersValidationBehavior { CharacterType = CharacterType.Digit, MaximumCharacterCount = 0 }
             }
           }
        }
            
     };
```

In the second scenario, where the validator is initialized in the `Entry`'s initizalization, is it possible to access the validator in order to check its state and if yes how?

Comment: Yes, use the Behaviors property

Comment: What would be the equivalent code of `myValidator.IsValid` in this case, to use as a condition of an if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to access the validator to check its state. Your code sample uses MultiValidationBehavior and its Child Behaviors (TextValidationBehavior and CharactersValidationBehavior).

Using the Entry's Behaviors collection, you can access MultiValidationBehavior and its Child Behaviors. By iterating over the Behaviors collection and finding the MultiValidationBehavior behavior, we can retrieve the MultiValidationBehavior. MultiValidationBehavior has a Children property that allows you to retrieve its Child Behaviors. Here's how you could access MultiValidationBehavior and its Child Behaviors.

```
// Find the MultiValidationBehavior in the Entry's Behaviors collection
MultiValidationBehavior multiValidationBehavior = null;
foreach (var behavior in myEntry.Behaviors)
{
    if (behavior is MultiValidationBehavior multiBehavior)
    {
        multiValidationBehavior = multiBehavior;
        break;
    }
}

// Check the state of the MultiValidationBehavior and its Child Behaviors
if (multiValidationBehavior != null)
{
    // Check the state of the MultiValidationBehavior
    bool isValid = multiValidationBehavior.IsValid;
    string errorMessage = multiValidationBehavior.ErrorMessage;

    // Check the state of the Child Behaviors
    foreach (var childBehavior in multiValidationBehavior.Children)
    {
        if (childBehavior is TextValidationBehavior textBehavior)
        {
            int minimumLength = textBehavior.MinimumLength;
            // Check other properties of the TextValidationBehavior
        }
        else if (childBehavior is CharactersValidationBehavior charBehavior)
        {
            CharacterType characterType = charBehavior.CharacterType;
            int maximumCharacterCount = charBehavior.MaximumCharacterCount;
            // Check other properties of the CharactersValidationBehavior
        }
        
    }
}
```

**myValidator.IsValid in an if statement's condition**

```
// Find the MultiValidationBehavior in the Entry's Behaviors collection
MultiValidationBehavior multiValidationBehavior = 
myEntry.Behaviors.OfType<MultiValidationBehavior>().FirstOrDefault();

// Check if the MultiValidationBehavior is valid
if (multiValidationBehavior?.IsValid == true)
{
    // MultiValidationBehavior is valid, do something here
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to write something similar to `myValidator.IsValid` in an if statement's condition, for the `MultiValidationBehavior`? I'm not interested in checking the children state, at least not at the moment.

Comment: Using myValidator.IsValid in an if statement's condition is possible. Check out the updated answer.